# Imagemagick caption text with shadow on top of resized image in one command

Tags: bash, imagemagick

I'm making a quick bash/imagemagick script that

1. Takes an image
2. Crops and resizes that image
3. Overlays a shadow of caption text sized to a box
4. Overlays white caption text sized to the same back

And puts that into a final image.

I am able to get the resized image as the background and the shadow of the text on top. However, I haven't been yet able to get the white text on top of the shadow text.

How can I achieve the desired output in a single imagemagick command (and without the PNG offset that gimp complains about when I open the result image)?

The code:

```
#!/bin/bash

text="Beef meatball filet mignon, andouille biltong sausage kielbasa. Landjaeger pancetta shankle, ham hock beef corned beef kevin meatball beef ribs short ribs. Landjaeger biltong shoulder, salami brisket shank bresaola leberkas tail corned beef jowl ham pig. Venison pork loin capicola ham hock pastrami, turducken ground round prosciutto landjaeger bacon t-bone."

image="abstract-waves-on-a-blue-background.jpg"

width=1024
height=768

padding=100

text_width=$(( $width-$padding ))
text_height=$(( $height-$padding ))

convert \
    -size "${text_width}x${text_height}" \
    -background none \
    -gravity center \
    -fill white \
    caption:"${text}" \
    -background none \
    -shadow 80x3+0+0 \
    +repage \
    \( \
    "${image}" \
    -resize "${width}x${height}^" \
    -gravity center \
    -crop "${width}x${height}+0+0" \
    \) \
    +swap \
    -gravity center \
    -composite \
    "output.png"
```

This is the output I'm getting:
[image: Bad Output]
The output I'd like:
[image: Good Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close... I think you need something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

text="Beef meatball filet mignon, andouille biltong sausage kielbasa. Landjaeger pancetta shankle, ham hock beef corned beef kevin meatball beef ribs short ribs. Landjaeger biltong shoulder, salami brisket shank bresaola leberkas tail corned beef jowl ham pig. Venison pork loin capicola ham hock pastrami, turducken ground round prosciutto landjaeger bacon t-bone."

image="bg.png"

width=1024
height=768

padding=100

text_width=$(( $width-$padding ))
text_height=$(( $height-$padding ))

convert \
    -size "${text_width}x${text_height}" \
    -background none \
    -gravity center \
    -fill white \
    caption:"${text}" \( +clone -shadow 80x3+0+0 \) +swap -layers merge \
    +repage \
    \( \
    "${image}" \
    -resize "${width}x${height}^" \
    -gravity center \
    -crop "${width}x${height}+0+0" \
    \) \
    +swap \
    -gravity center \
    -composite +repage \
    "output.png"
```

Comment: I found this works, but it's too slow, and will cost few seconds.